# Rails "logic" seems to be alluding me

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Well, as usual I've tied myself into another knot with rails "logic", and am frustrated beyond belief.

If I could pull this off in regular SQL it would like:

```
SELECT points.genus, types.type_name
FROM types, points
WHERE types.id = points.type_id and genus='Malus';
```

I can't seem to mimic the output of this query in rails.  The best I seem to be able to hope for is:

```
Point
  .select(:genus, :type_id)
  .where("genus = 'Malus'")
  .joins(:type)
```

Great, I can rely on rails associations to output the correct value in my view by adding a `belongs_to :type` entry in my `point.rb' and everything comes out hunky-dory.

However, I need to pass types.type_name to some code in the model.  Everything works as expected if I use `:type_id` (other than getting a value rather than the string I need).  I've tried `'types.type_name'` and `:type_name` both of which generates a NIL.  `:type.type_name` generates the following error:

> undefined method `type_name' for :types:Symbol

As a side note, I didn't create the code I'm trying to pass the string to in the model. It is building JSON from the variables I pass it, and doesn't care if its a string or a number, nor how many variables I pass it.

**--Update to add actual code rather than just theory, per @Dan's request --**

**`create_points.rb`**

```
class CreatePoints < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :points do |t|
      t.string :genus
      t.string :species
      t.string :cultivar
      t.string :common_name
      t.references :type, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false, default: Time.now
      t.multi_point :geom, srid: 4326
    end
end
```

**`create_types.rb`**

```
class CreateTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :types do |t|
      t.string :type_name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
```

**`plants_controller.rb`**

```
class PlantsController < ApplicationController
  def map
    @points = Point
      .select('points.genus, points.species, points.cultivar, points.common_name, types.type_name')
      .where("types.type_name like 'Tree-%' or types.type_name like 'Shrub-%' or types.type_name like 'Perennial' or types.type_name like 'Fern' or types.type_name like 'Vine-%'")
      .order(:id)
      .eager_load(:type)
    feature_collection = Point.to_feature_collection @points
    @geojson = RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(feature_collection)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @geojson }
      format.html
    end
```

**`type.rb`**

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :points
end
```

**`point.rb`**

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
  include Featurable

  featurable :geom, [:genus, :species, :cultivar, :common_name, :type_id]
end
```

**`concerns/featurable.rb`**

```
module Featurable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def featurable geom_attr_name, property_names = []
      define_method :to_feature do
        factory = RGeo::GeoJSON::EntityFactory.instance

        property_names = Array(property_names)
        properties = property_names.inject({}) do |hash, property_name|
          hash[property_name.to_sym] = read_attribute(property_name)
          hash
        end
        factory.feature read_attribute(geom_attr_name), self.id, properties
      end
    end

    # turns a collection of models to a feature collection
    # All models in the collection should implement the to_feature method
    def to_feature_collection models
      factory = RGeo::GeoJSON::EntityFactory.instance
      features = models.map(&:to_feature)
      factory.feature_collection features
    end
  end
end
```

In the `featurable :geom, [:genus ...` line I would like to use the value of type.type_name rather then point.type_id.

**--Update 2 to repost `point.rb`--**

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :type
  include Featurable

  def to_feature
    factory = RGeo::GeoJSON::EntityFactory.instance

    property_names = [:genus, :species, :cultivar, :common_name, :type_name]

    properties = property_names.inject({}) do |hash, property_name|
      hash[property_name] = self.send(property_name)
      hash
    end
    factory.feature geom, self.id, properties
  end

  delegate :type_name, to: :type
  featurable :geom, [:genus, :species, :cultivar, :common_name, :type]
end
```

Comment: If you could include code snippets from the two models in question showing your relations and maybe the structure of the two tables it might help generate some more responses.

Comment: @dan I've added all my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you should not try to retrieve all the required columns from different tables in the same statement, although as a SQL-oriented person I understand that instinct.

I think that the key to this is to change to be:

```
featurable :geom, [:genus, :species, :cultivar, :common_name, :type_name]
```

... and then to get the Point instance to respond to #type_name with an appropriate value. You can do that with:

```
delegate :type_name, to: :type
```

You should only need to eager load or join to :type in the definition of @points in order to make that efficient.

Edit: Because of the use of read_attribute, you might have to define your own to_feature method in Point.

```
def to_feature
  factory = RGeo::GeoJSON::EntityFactory.instance

  property_names = [:genus, :species, :cultivar, :common_name, :type_name]

  properties = property_names.inject({}) do |hash, property_name|
    hash[property_name] = self.send(property_name)
    hash
  end
  factory.feature geom, self.id, properties
end
```

Comment: thank you so much for attempting to help me. :)  I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting.  Simply adding the delegate line to my model didn't change the JSON output.  Combining the delegate command and removing the `_name` from the featurable line resulted in an error.

Comment: Adding the delegate and using :type_name ought to have done it, but actually the select in the definition of @point should be removed also, i think.

Comment: Would you like a link to a bitbucket repo with a copy of the DB?

Comment: Oh no definitely not. I wonder if the issue here is the read_attribute() in the definition of featurable. That seems like a poor choice. It might be worth considering adding an explicit #to_feature method to Point and not calling featurable at all. I'l add something to the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really not understanding the changes. I've updated my original post with the code for `point.rb` as I've understood you to suggest.

Comment: Take the "featurable :geom, [:genus, :species, :cultivar, :common_name, :type]" line out, as it's defining a new #to_feature that is overriding the one you specified

Comment: Seems to have done it!  Thanks much - now onto troubleshooting the new error generated by the coffeescript that is receiving the data. :)

Answer (score -1):

You might try:

```
Point
  .select('points.genus, types.type_name')
  .where("genus = ?", "Malus")
  .joins(:type)
```

Comment: sorry if my post was a little confusion - the select command wasn't the issue, it's accessing the method that is causing me fits.  Here's the original code `featurable :geom, [:genus,  :type_id]`  However I really need that value from types.type_name.  On a side note, when I type your suggestion into rails console, it completely ignores the type.type_name field is the data it returns.